# Apache common email with vaadin7?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying use the API common mail to send email with my vaadin project. I add the jar file in my buildpath and in WEB-INF/lib but does not work.

This API works with vaadin ? If not works which I can use ?

Comment: what does not work? any exceptions? any stacktrace?

Comment: When I try use SimpleMail on my project does not import the API. I do try import "import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail" but does't work also. The problem is that I can't import the packages of API and I don't understand why not import if I added API on my Build Path.

Comment: That rather looks like an IDE problem. I'm sure it'll work as soon as you fixed that. Which IDE do you use?

Comment: I guess so !!! I'm using Eclipse Kepler. The stranger is that I use others libs and does work, for example mysql-connection.jar works.

Comment: Try to refresh the whole project within eclipse. Show a printscreen of your bildpath.

Comment: I did refresh and close/open Eclipse and not work...here the printscreen: http://dc191.4shared.com/img/Tg1XfqJc/s7/142ed4079d8/Captura_de_tela_de_2013-12-13_.png

Comment: I've given an answer according to your printscreen and coments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Apache Common Mail you also need the [JavaMail API](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home). Add this jar to your buildpath & WEB-INF/lib folder as well.